# Issues with creating SQL Server table relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

First table:

```
create table abc
(
    AId  INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    EMP NVARCHAR(50)

    CONSTRAINT PK_abc PRIMARY KEY (AId, Name)
)
```

And second table as:

```
create table def
(
    AId  INT,
    Comment NVARCHAR(50)

    constraint FK_aid FOREIGN KEY (AId) references abc (AId)
)
```

This throws an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'abc' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_aid'.

So I updated as:

```
create table def
(
    AId  INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    Comment NVARCHAR(50)

    constraint FK_AID FOREIGN KEY (AId, Name) references abc (AId, Name)
)
```

But this throws another error:

> More than one key specified in column level FOREIGN KEY constraint, table 'def'.

Not sure what am I missing here.

---Updated----

Sorry for giving vague example. I was having difficulty in explaining my problem here. I have attached the screenshot of my problem. This show the eventual output that I am expecting by making join to 3 tables. Where the data of 3 tables is populated from an input form.

I have tried to provide in a clear way. Let me know if you need more inputs.

Attchment at:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OPEY.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Help us help you.  `abc` and `def` is a very bad table name, and doesn't help you at all.  No one knows which table id dependent on which table.  Use a meaningful table name, eg: `Order` and `OrderDetail`.  This, people will know which table depend on which table.

Comment: I picture of a spreadsheet doesn't give much help. You may want to step back, re-think your actual question, and start over. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an identity column.  Use it as the primary key:

```
create table abc (
    AId  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    EMP NVARCHAR(50)
);

create table def (
    AId  INT,
    Comment NVARCHAR(50)
    constraint FK_aid FOREIGN KEY (AId) references abc (AId)
);
```

`Name` should not be in the definition of the primary key.

Comment: And although I'm sure you're giving us a stripped down version of your table definitions, Name should be two fields; one for first name and another for last name. Just in case that's not already the case.

Comment: Thanks , what if I want to have both id and name as primary key . What options do I have to use them as foreign key in my second table

Comment: @kaka1234 . . . You don't want to have both name and id as a primary key.  Perhaps you want `name` to be unique and `id` as the primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my post. Would appreciate if you can provide any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to do it as a separate statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[def]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_def_abc] FOREIGN KEY([AId], [Name])
REFERENCES [dbo].[abc] ([AId], [Name])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[def] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_def_abc]
GO
```

But you still should **NOT** do that.  Identity is unique and it alone should be used as primary key.

Comment: I give up.  What part of make `AId  INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY` on `abc` is not clear?  Gordon provided the exact syntax.

Comment: did you see my updated post where I have posted the image of my requirement.

Comment: I already gave up.  SO is not a coding service. You got an answer to the stated question.